# Whats the Correct Product Type

Tags: product, products, custom-product-type

What would be the correct product type to use for example we are selling a Printer.

Then we want to add a dropdown for what Color of Printer Ink they want to buy.

I don't think its a bundled product since the Printer is a fix Variable only the Color of the Ink has options.

Thank You

Comment: You can create Simple product with options.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

> **Configurable product**

A configurable product appears to be a single product with lists of options for each variation. However, each option represents a separate.

This kind of product includes many simple products. The collection of various products with different options of colors and sizes.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-types.html

https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/6-types-product-types-magento-2.html

Comment: Hello, Thank You for your response. I think the configurable product is only applicable for color and sizes dropdown but it does not count the stock of the main product. As per my example above, the inventory will only be updated for the Color of the Ink but not the Printer. How do we account for the Stock of the Printer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create simple product with custom option color.